# How do I use ActiveMQ in Apache Flink?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am getting my data through ActiveMQ which I want to process in real time with Apache Flink DataStreams. There is support for many messaging services like RabbitMQ and Kafka but I can't see any support for ActiveMQ. How can I use it?

Comment: There is activemq support now: https://github.com/apache/bahir-flink/tree/master/flink-connector-activemq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a JMS connector for Flink:

https://github.com/jkirsch/senser/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/tuberlin/senser/images/flink/io/FlinkJMSStreamSource.java

Answer (score 3):

Since there is not support for `ActiveMQ`, I would recommend implement a custom source.

You basically have to implement the `SourceFunction` interface.
If you want to have exactly-once semantics, you can base your implementation on the `MultipleIdsMessageAcknowledgingSourceBase` class.

I would recommend you to start with implementing a `SourceFunction`

Comment: Check out this example: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/NiFiSource.java